# App:Gradle Build error while adding fb SDK

Tags: android, facebook, api, build

Friends, getting the following dependency errors while adding FB SDK to my Android APP

Error:
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0

Snapshot of my APP: Gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    // useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unwiredmetrics.priceplanoptimization"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a correct syntax like :

```
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```